# Why is my PLSQL trigger validation not failing on error?

Tags: plsql, triggers, uppercase

I'm coding a simple PL/SQL trigger to check if the values to insert or update are UPPER, the trigger has compilated fine but is not working when I insert or update a record. Do you have any idea? Thanks

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_case_trg
BEFORE
INSERT OR UPDATE
ON unidades_medidas
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    e_invalid_case EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    IF
        :NEW.unm_codigo <> UPPER(:NEW.unm_codigo) OR
        :NEW.unm_descripcion <> UPPER(:NEW.unm_descripcion)
        THEN
            RAISE e_invalid_case;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN e_invalid_case THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
            'Nuevos datos deben estar en mayúsculas');
END check_case_trg;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Comment: Incidentally, this might be better implemented as a check constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DBMS_OUTPUT` is a debugging tool - it does not raise errors or exceptions.

To ensure that your trigger stops the insert or update, you must ensure that an exception is raised. A good way to do this is to use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` because it gives you control over what exception is reported to the calling process, e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_case_trg
BEFORE
INSERT OR UPDATE
ON unidades_medidas
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF
        :NEW.unm_codigo <> UPPER(:NEW.unm_codigo) OR
        :NEW.unm_descripcion <> UPPER(:NEW.unm_descripcion)
        THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Nuevos datos deben estar en mayúsculas');
    END IF;
END check_case_trg;
```

p.s. I have to second WW's comment that this should most probably be implemented as a check constraint on the table.

Comment: Jeffrey you are a PLSQL monster! Trigger works fine and now I understand your directives. I know I can add a constraint to check case but the first step of the excercise was create a trigger to check case. Thanks for your help. Of course I vote your answer rigth. Thanks again!